# c, how do i detect if another process is writing to a file

Tags: c, file-io, fopen

I do open large files with fopen under c with a kind-of observed folder logic.
I'd like to fopen (or at least to fread) the file as soon as it has been copied completely to my observed folder.

How can i detect if another process is writing to a file?
Is that possible with standard-c?

Thanks

Comment: This depends on your OS. If you're on a GNU-based system, grab the source for 'fuser', which lists all open files on a system. That'll show you the API calls necessary for what you want. There are also other utilities that can monitor file system operations and run other processes when conditions are met, but again, those are OS-dependent.

Comment: something along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use

Comment: also look at http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/flocking.html  look at "inotify"

Comment: flock() the file in the writing process and unlock it when you're done, then use flock() with F_TEST in the other process to check if it's locked

Comment: @strkol With his description it doesn't seem he has control over the writing process

Comment: @Pavan Manjunath, OK then one ugly linux specific solution is to check in /proc if the file is among the open FDs. The other one is to use fanotify (also linux specific) to monitor when the file is being created and closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do it with standard C.  The best you can do is heuristically notice when file stops changing, e.g. read the last few blocks of the file, sleep *n* seconds, then read the blocks again and compare against the previous read.  You could also try just watching the end of file seek pointer to see when it stops moving, but for large files (size greater than what will fit in a signed long) the POSIX function ftello() is required to do it portably.

Comment: fseek to the end and compare the file size is what i'm doing now. It looks like that it works for my case. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It's kind of "rude" but you could keep trying to open it in write mode; as long as it's being written to by some other file, the `fopen` will fail.  Something like this:

```
FILE* f;
while( (f = fopen( fname, "w" )) == NULL ) {
  sleep( 100 );  // we want to be moderately polite by not continually hitting the file
}
```

Comment: I dont think this works. `fopen` does not check whether anybody's already writing into a file AFAIK. Can you link up some documentation regarding this?

Comment: It turns out you're right...at least I learned something in the process.  Thanks for calling me on that, Pavan.